# Protected routes in React

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am trying to create some protected in routes in React, using Create React App 2 and React Router 4. I used Tyler McGinnis's [Protected Routes](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/) article as an example.  Here is the my basic app component.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { loggedIn: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('did mount');
    this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
  }

  render() {
    fakeAuth.authenticate(this.state.loggedIn);
    console.log('render');

    return (
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Login />
          <PrivateRoute path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Chordsheets />
          <Chordsheet />
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true 
        ? <Component {...props} /> 
        : <Redirect to="/" />
   )}
  />
);

const fakeAuth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  authenticate(state) {
    this.isAuthenticated = state;
    console.log('isAuthenticated', this.isAuthenticated);
  }
};

const Login = () => (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
  </div>
);

const Chordsheets = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Route path="/chordsheets" component={Header} />
    <Route path="/chordsheets" component={AllChordSheets} />
  </Fragment>
);

const Chordsheet = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Route path="/chordsheet/:id" component={Header} />
    <Route path="/chordsheet/:id" component={ChordSheet} />
  </Fragment>
);

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className="links">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/chordsheets/0">My Chordsheets</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};
```

After the component mounts `loggedIn` is set to true. When going to a new route render is not called again, so I cannot get to the `Register` route.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to structure this? Thanks!

Comment: if you want get into Register, your url need '/register'. I don't see any redirect to '/register'

Comment: I edited my post, my Private Route component was incorrect. If `isAuthenticated` is true it should render the component, if not it redirects them to the home route.

Answer (score 0):

I know that i'm late but i'm happy to help anyone he wants this functionality by taking a look to this [protected-react-routes-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protected-react-routes-generator)

All you're going to do is to provide the routes as an array.